# KML Layer Will Not Toggle Properly, Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, toggle, kml, layer

I'm in the process of creating an interactive campus map using the Google Maps API and KML. I have a map with a Ground Overlay and a layer of KML markers. I am trying to figure out how to get the KML layer to toggle. I currently have it set to toggle via a checkbox, but it only toggles off the first time you click the checkbox. Any subsequent clicks do nothing. The KML layer just disappears. I have a feeling that this is probably an easy javascript fix, but I'm new to javascript and I can't figure it out. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your help.

Here's all my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

  var map;
  var omaha = new google.maps.LatLng(41.265437, -95.947405);

  var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'blue';

  var stylez = [
    {
      featureType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#004A96" },
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "labels",
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#000000" },
      ]
    },
        {
      featureType: "road",
      elementType: "local",
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#24356B" },
        { saturation: 55 },
        { lightness: 20 }
      ]
    },
    {
      featureType: "poi.school",
      elementType: "geometry",
      stylers: [
        { hue: "#24356B" },
        { saturation: 55 },
        { lightness: 20 }
      ]
    }
  ];

  var imageBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.2599,-95.9601),
      new google.maps.LatLng(41.2718,-95.9367));

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    center: omaha,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
    },
    mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var styledMapOptions = {
    name: "Blue"
  };

  var jayzMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez, styledMapOptions);

  map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, jayzMapType);

  var oldmap = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      "http://www.mcography.com/beta/CampusMap.png",
      imageBounds);
  oldmap.setMap(map);

  var kmlLayer01URL = 'http://www.mcography.com/beta/CUADA.kml';
  var kmlOptions = {
            preserveViewport: 1
    };
    kmlLayer01 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlLayer01URL, kmlOptions);
    kmlLayer01.setMap(map); 
    // initially show KML Layer 01
    document.getElementById('show_hide_KML_Layer_01').checked = true; 

}

function toggleKMLLayer01() {
    if (!document.getElementById('show_hide_KML_Layer_01').checked)
      kmlLayer01.setMap(null);
    else
      kmlLayer01.setMap(map); }

</script>
</head>

<body onload="initialize()">

    <p><input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_KML_Layer_01" onclick="toggleKMLLayer01();" />ADA Layer</p> 
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Where is `map` declared? Is it in scope when you call `setMap` in `toggleKMLLayer01`?

Comment: Is this what you mean?
     var map;
   var omaha = new google.maps.LatLng(41.265437, -95.947405);
    var mapOptions = {
     zoom: 15,
     center: omaha,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
     },
     mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
     };

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

Comment: That is partly what I mean. Can you edit your question to include that? You have a random `}` halfway through the JS in your question... where is the matching `{`?

Comment: Sure, I just pasted all of the code in so you could look at the whole thing. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: No problem! Now that you've shown the `map` declaration, you can see that it's out of scope. It is only available inside the `initialize` function. Move the `var map;` outside of `initialize` so it's in the global scope (as is mentioned by @HeitorChang in his answer).

Comment: Thanks so much @James! It works! These forums are wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the top part of your code, I can't be totally sure, but my hunch is that you need to make the `map` variable global, otherwise `toggle` won't `setMap` to `map`. I wrote the following, which works:

```
  var map;

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0), zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var kmlLayer01URL = 'http://www.mcography.com/beta/CUADA.kml';
    var kmlOptions = {
      preserveViewport: 1
    };
    kmlLayer01 = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlLayer01URL, kmlOptions);
    kmlLayer01.setMap(map); 
    // initially show KML Layer 01
    document.getElementById('show_hide_KML_Layer_01').checked = true; 
  }

  function toggleKMLLayer01() {
    if (!document.getElementById('show_hide_KML_Layer_01').checked)
      kmlLayer01.setMap(null);
    else
      kmlLayer01.setMap(map); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Heitor. To make the map variable global, I just delete var from in front of it, correct? I did this and the toggling still does not work.

Comment: Yes, delete the var, but also, you have to write `var map` above (and outside) `initialize`. It looks out of place, but needs to be there.

Comment: can we have multiple link inside same var kmlLayer01URL ?

Comment: @Nadia without more details about your problem, i can only say that you need either an array or object to store multiple URLs under the same variable name. consider asking a new question, if it's unrelated to this one.